# Missing ] after element list error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm using ajax to get what the user has selected in a "select" box and sending it to a php file. Then i need to make the results of a query, with those selection results, are downloadable. So just to reiterate, when they click something jquery/ajax sends it to php. php  returns a list of things for them to select again, this happens until they have selected five options. Then, below the select boxes, a link appears saying export(download). That link should send them to a php function export() along with a get saying the stored procedure name i need to export. Along with 5 selection results as parameters in the stored procedure. Hope that made sense. here's my code.

PHP sending results to js file-------

```
 $jsStr = '[';
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
            $jsStr .= '["'. $row->count_result .'","'. $row->count_desc .'","'. $row->count_SP .'",'. $cn .','. $gp .','. $co .','. $st .','. $dp .']';
        }
        $jsStr = substr($jsStr,0,-1);
    }
    $jsStr .= ']';

    return 'changeResults('. $jsStr .');';
```

JS ----------------

```
 function changeResults (data) {
    $('#systems').html(data[0][0] +' - '+ data[0][1] +' <a href="http://95.211.130.165:8080/index.php/discovery/export?sp='+ data[0][2] +'&cn='+ data[0][3] +'&gp='+ data[0][4] +'&co='+ data[0][5] +'&st='+ data[0][6] +'&dp='+ data[0][7] +'">Export</a>');
    $('#users').html(data[1][0] +' - '+ data[1][1] +' <a href="http://95.211.130.165:8080/index.php/discovery/export?sp='+ data[1][2] +'&cn='+ data[1][3] +'&gp='+ data[1][4] +'&co='+ data[1][5] +'&st='+ data[1][6] +'&dp='+ data[1][7] +'">Export</a>');
}
```

Error I get from firebug

missing ] after element list
[Break On This Error]

...NV02) - Users counted in selected scope","usr_disc_Inv_usr_content",1,1,1,1,1])

Let me know if anything is unclear, Thanks!

Comment: It's hard to tell without showing us either: 1) the value of the string generated by the PHP, or 2) the value of each column used to build the string within the PHP.

Comment: What do you mean the value of the string or column?

Comment: You should consider [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/json_encode), as it does the whole encoding for you and it's a lot faster than pure PHP...

Comment: I must ask if we're missing some logic here? What exactly are you setting the values to in your PHP? are you trying to dump a query results to JSON? `json_encode()` not work for you?

Comment: @Radu you got me by ten seconds... mainly due to my attempt at understanding this heap :P

Comment: You really should be using `json_encode`. I am disappointed that you accepted the quick fix answer rather than any of the better options.

Comment: I dont know what json_encode is. I'll look into it and probably will use it but right now i just needed something that works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't really know JavaScript or anything you use. But it looks to me as if you remove the last `]` added within the `foreach loop` by

```
$jsStr = substr($jsStr,0,-1);
```

I think you had a comma at the end of the line in the `foreach`. Like this:

```
foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
    $jsStr .= '["'. $row->count_result .'","'. $row->count_desc .'","'. $row->count_SP .'",'. $cn .','. $gp .','. $co .','. $st .','. $dp .'],';
}
```

That way it makes more sense to me. To get the bracketing correct you either have to add this comma back (which I think is the right notation) or remove the `substr` operation.

Comment: id would be better if @dylan would use json_encode/decode, my 2 cents

Comment: You my friend are a gentleman and a scholar. I dont know what json is but it was the comma. I must have accidently deleted that. Thanks zpea

Comment: Yeah, probably. joeframbach's answer does look a lot cleaner. So basically this is the quick fix for Dylan's current implementation. Joe's answer is what he should actually use :)

Comment: Thanks, Dylan. And believe me, I know chasing forgotten commas or brackets from my own code ;)

Comment: Extra commas are allowed in php. It's javascript that complains about it.

Comment: sorry, joe. Just moved my comment from here to your answer as I gained the privilege to comment everywhere. And OK, PHP always seemed to have interesting diversions from all the other languages it resembles :)

Answer (score 4):

Let's clean this up a lot!

```
    $jsArr = array();
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
            $jsArr[] = array(
                $row->count_result,
                $row->count_desc,
                $row->count_SP,
                $cn,
                $gp,
                $co,
                $st,
                $dp,
            );
        }
    }
    $jsStr = json_encode($jsArr);

    return 'changeResults('. $jsStr .');';
```

Comment: Yeah, that looks good. However I think there is a comma too much in `$dp,` (?)

Comment: OK, I see PHP is different :)

Comment: Trailing commas are allowed in php. Personally, I like it. Suppose you want to comment out the last line, or hastily copy-paste in a new element. Having the comma there serves to remind you that this is a list and to add a comma.

Comment: @joeframbach Yeah, definitely sounds handy.

Answer (score 3):

The line:

```
$jsStr = substr($jsStr,0,-1);
```

You're removing the `]` from the end of your string.  That's why. Not sure why that line is in there.